# How can I implement a plugin on element with exception of inner element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to implement a plugin of highlight on a class of `div`.
The problem that the `div` contains a `span` which I don't want to be highlighted.

How can I implement the highlight without affecting the specific `span`?

I call the highlight plugin with this code:

$('element which should be highlight').highlight('the string to be highlight')

```
<div class="row clearfix allDiv">
  bla bla hello heloo
 <div class='form-group employe-detail'>
<span class="default-user-avtar">bla bla<span>
<span class="employe-name" >${member?.user?.lastname}, ${member?.user?.firstname}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I need something like:
$('.allDiv except span with class default-user-avtar').highlight('bla bla')

I tried :

```
$('.allDiv').not('default-user-avtar').highlight('bla bla')
```

It didn't work. All the 'bla bla' in the div include the specific span were highlighted.

Comment: Add your code plz. Also a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the issue would be great.

Comment: It doesn't highlight the default-user-avtar span. How it would, as the "Highlight" plugin searches for the specific text to be highlighted. See http://jsfiddle.net/maLmmpnw/1/

Answer (score 1):

So you are using already existed plugin. If it doesn't provide some sort of `exclude` option the following trick might work.

```
$('.allDiv').highlight('bla').find('.default-user-avtar').unhighlight();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maLmmpnw/2/)